Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services not working
I'm using Windows 11 Pro x64 fully patched. I'm trying to experiment with a service that uses Active Directory for authentication.
Install a unique instance of AD LDS.

Instance name: win-ad
Computers will connect to this instance of AD LDS using the following ports:
LDAP port: 389
SSL port: 636

AD LDS replication will use Negotiate authentication.

Store AD LDS data files in the following location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADAM\win-ad\data

Store AD LDS log files in the following location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADAM\win-ad\data

Run AD LDS using the following account:
NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Set up the following account to administer AD LDS:
xxx\xxx

Create the following application directory partition:
CN=spinnaker,DC=xxxsoftware,DC=com 

Import these LDIF files:
MS-User.LDF

Everything starts successfully. When I run powershell and run:
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=spinnaker,DC=xxxsoftware,DC=com" -server localhost:389

I get:
Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it
does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

If I try telnet to localhost 389, the port is open and listening.
What am I missing? Every tutorial on AD LDS seems like this should work.
I should also note that ADSI Edit and SysInternals AD Explorer are able to connect.

The PowerShell AD cmdlets weren't actually written to talk LDAP – they instead rely on an additional AD Web Services API that comes with Windows Server 2008+ and which would provide a HTTP-based frontend to the AD LDAP service.
AD LDS is not the same thing as Active Directory – it is only the barebones LDAP directory component of AD, so it doesn't come with AD Web Services, which means you cannot use it with the "standard" PowerShell cmdlets.
(As far as I remember, it doesn't come with a Kerberos KDC for authentication, either, and that would be a major part of AD usage.)
If you're sure that AD LDS suits your needs, then you will need to use either ADSIEdit or the PowerShell [adsi] interface – https://stackoverflow.com/a/71745718 has an example – or various other LDAP-based tools. For example, I think PSOpenAD is LDAP-based and provides similar cmdlets. I sometimes use Apache Directory Studio and python-ldap to manage AD (we run Samba AD, which is mostly full AD but also lacks ADWS).
For proper experiments you can download Windows Server for free from Microsoft and run it in a VM; they offer "trial" images that work for 120 days. (Or indefinitely if you want.)

I'm trying to use it for this: https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/other_config/security/authentication/ldap/ which seems like it should be good enough. But if the standard cmdlets don't work, I guess that's my answer, thanks.

I was following this guide: https://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/02/step-step-guide-setup-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds/ and they seem to work for him, but he is running on Windows Server, but still installing LDS.

Yes, so they probably selected AD Web Services in the "Features" step (which they omitted in the tutorial). Most likely it doesn't matter to AD WS what kind of LDAP service it finds on port 389, so if you're on Windows Server and have installed the component, then the cmdlets would work – but if you're on Windows 10 and have only AD LDS, then they won't.
